# How to make TSC infer that a call overload has been used, without explicitly checking every parameter

Tags: typescript

Take a function that has two signature overloads:

```
type f64 = number;

function add(): f64;
function add(x: f64, y: f64): f64;
function add(x?: f64, y?: f64): f64 {
    return typeof x === "number"
        ? x + y
        : 0;
}
```

For clarification, that code above fails on the attempted addition, as `y` is potentially `undefined`.

But, if `x` is a number, then, by extension, parameter `y` *must* also be a number, as there are no overloads that allow `x` to be a number, without `y` *also* being a number.

Can I make TSC infer/understand that, without the redundant double check: `typeof x === "number" && typeof y === "number"`?

Note that actually attempting to call it like that isn't allowed:

```
add(1, undefined);
```

Fails with:

> Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.(2345) 
> The call would have succeeded against this implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible.

I had a class with two overloads, the first would accept no parameters, the other would take two parameters of different types. It was originally written in JS, but converting it to TS would require a restructure, or additional assertions, which I feel are unecessary.

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&useDefineForClassFields=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&esModuleInterop=false&removeComments=true&checkJs=true&experimentalDecorators=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=99&ts=4.2.0-dev.20210114#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gWxNpMAngFzwCCMMUhAQgK4BmDIMA3AFCiSwIN0pgMAS1TwoECEjBQMIABQBKUijrYARiw7tuaNPACqQlBgox4IAB6yUwPYeMAOU9XgBvdgEhk6DDDqCCRVZ4AHoQ+CQANxZJKGB4AEZPb0w-AJg5UPComKQ4+AAmTw81RmYYUmdaMpYAGmK1QlkAeSY0EAxlVQ0YTwUOL1RU-wxAhpqYAH5Kymp6JjqGppBWhnaMafgVdRY+t2KUrAAHXy6dswBeeFKFy4ur3HwiYo9J6+XV9ayI6JhY+KSHiBpHEkmksiC3xyfzy8SKxTQdCOLDkjwIhFq8BOMExCQAbP1PABfdhE1hAA)

From TS's site:

> Types provide a way to describe the shape of an object, providing better documentation, and allowing TypeScript to validate that your code is working correctly.

This is code that would always work correctly, provided that it is called through one of the signature overloads, which TSC should guarantee that it is.

Changing the implementation of the already-working code to comply with TS is off of the table.

---

Update, the closest that I've gotten is this:

```
function add<T extends f64 | undefined>(x: T, y: T extends f64 ? f64 : never): f64 {
    return typeof x === "number"
        ? x + y
        : 0;
}

add(1, 2); // okay

add(); // expected 2 params

add(undefined); // must be (undefined, never)
```

Comment: `x?: number` means `x` is an _optional_ parameter of type `number | undefined`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad That's nothing new to me. Is there anything that implied otherwise? Do you have a better solution to this than the currently posted one?

Comment: My point is that the type of `x` says nothing about the presence of `y`

Comment: @AluanHaddad `f64?` is only used to comply with the overloads, is there another way to have done that? Maybe generics and ternaries?

Comment: Maybe `return x ?? 0 + y ?? 0`. I agree that it's an annoying problem because I don't like to change the implementation logic just to satisfy the types

Comment: @AluanHaddad I was thinking of somthing like `add<T extends f64 | undefined>(x: T, y: T)`, how can I make `T` literially one of the two separate types?

Comment: The problem is the optionality `?`. It adds undefined back into the type  regardless. There are a few ways to write it. At this point, I would favor either `function add(x = 0, y = 0): f64 { return x + y; }` or `function add(x?: any, y?: any): f64 { return x !== undefined ? x + y : 0; }`.

Answer (score 0):

**First approach**

```js
type f64 = number;

function add(...args: []): f64
function add(...args: [x: number, y: number]): f64

function add(...args: [x: number, y: number] | []): f64 {
  if (args.length === 2) {
    const [x, y] = args;
    return x + y
  }
  if (args.length === 1) { } // expected error

  return 0
}

const result = add() // ok
const result1 = add(1) // expected error
const result2 = add(1, 2) // ok
const result3 = add(1, 2, 3) // expected error
```

**Second approach**

```js
type f64 = number;

function add(): f64;
function add(x: f64, y: f64): f64;
function add(x?: f64, y?: f64): f64 {
  return x && y
    ? x + y
    : 0;
}

const result = add() // ok
const result1 = add(1) // error
const result2 = add(1, 2) // ok
const result3 = add(1,undefined) // error
const result4 = add(0,0) // ok
```

**Third approach**

```js
declare const memory: ArrayBuffer;
declare function allocate(): number;

class UintArr extends Uint8Array {
    constructor(); // overload 1
    constructor( // overload 2
        buffer: ArrayBuffer,
        byteOffset: number
    );
    constructor(
        buffer?: ArrayBuffer,
        byteOffset?: number
    ) {
        const ptr = buffer === memory // just add |undefined or remove explicit types at all
            ? byteOffset // overload 1
            : allocate(); // overload 2

        super(memory, ptr, 16);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'll update the post right now, but add(0, 0) would be an error for your second method, wouldn't it?